# Activity Feed: Method and best practices

Tags: info-visualisation, activity-feed

I am trying to create some kind of activity/recommendation feed where the user would be able to see news/updates of specific topics of interest that have a specific time stamp. For example it could be a feed of concerts in your area, of the music groups that you like and that are popular. I would also like to use two kind of visualisations for the feed items a single item container (Facebook like) and a group listing (like the recommendations in Tweeter).

My question is **does someone know if there is a scoring algorithm that I can use to define the order of the items in the feed** (those that are more near time, location and popularity should come first but I would also like super popular concerts in other cities if they are from a group that you like).

**Also I am wondering if these kind of feeds should be limited somehow**. For example if there are 30 concerts during the next month and 40 in the month after that maybe it is not interesting for the users to see all these items.

And last but not least, **is there a visualisation rule regarding how many single feed items there should be before you get a list item** or how I can successfully randomise this.

Comment: In the case of concerts, just knowing when the concert happens usually isn't good enough.  When the tickets go on sale is arguably just as important to a user who cares about getting a good seat.

Comment: @cimmanon thanks for the comment. Concerts was only an example. My question is more about how to weight different parameters (time, popularity, likes) in order to create such a feed and how succeed in terms of user experience (limitations & visual rules)

Comment: Could you provide more details regarding your third question? Also you might get more responses if you stick to asking one question at a time on the site.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your scoring algorithm questions, you might find this [presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/danmckinley/etsy-activity-feeds-architecture) by Dan McKinley from Etsy useful.

For your second question, you might want to have your site initially display fewer items in the feed, but auto load additional items when the user scrolls to the bottom of the feed.

Comment: Thanks I have already found this presentation and I think it's a very interesting to read